# Resultado inesperado utilizando string.split()

Tags: javascript, string, split

Dado el siguiente código:

```js
   function myFunction() {
        var str = "<tr><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td>td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td></tr><tr><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td></tr>";
        var res = str.split("<tr>");
        var resultado = res.length; //3   
        console.log(resultado);       
    }
    
 myFunction();
```

No entiendo porque la variable resultado toma el valor 3 en lugar de 2, si solo tengo dos etiquetas de tipo `<tr>`.

¿Cómo podría contar correctamente los resultados?

Answer (score 14):

### ¿Por qué se obtiene ese resultado?

Este es el **comportamiento correcto** de `split()`, ya que la función toma los caracteres anteriores y posteriores al **elemento de separación** (en este caso`<tr>`)

Puedes leer sobre `split()` en:

- [MDN - String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [ECMAScript - 21.1.3.17 String.prototype.split ( separator, limit )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.split)

### **Ejemplo**:

```js
var foo = "bar";
console.log(foo.split("bar"));
```

Si bien quieres separar por el string completo *"bar"*, `split()` va a tomar lo **anterior al separador** y lo **posterior al separador**, y al ser este la palabra entera retornará un array con dos posiciones, cada una de ellas almacenando el string vacío `("")`.

### **Sobre el problema planteado:**

Para el caso en que planteas split() retornara un array con las siguientes **tres** posiciones:

```
0:""
1:"<td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td>td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td></tr>"
2 :"<td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td></tr>"
```

```js
 var str = "<tr><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td>td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td></tr><tr><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td></tr>";
console.log(str.split("<tr>"));
```

La **primera** posicion refiere a **lo anterior a la primera ocurrencia** de `<tr>`, lo cual es el **string vacío**.

Por lo tanto, para obtener cuantas etiquetas `<tr>` existen debes **restarle 1** al largo del array resultado de `split()`

```
var trOcurrencies = str.split("<tr>").length-1;
```

### Otra manera de resolverlo:

También puedes utilizar una **expresión regular** que matchee con el string `<tr>` y tenga en cuenta todas las ocurrencias, es decir, no se detenga al encontrar la primera. Esto último lo puedes expresar mediante la opción `/g` de [matcheo global](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)

```js
var str= "<tr><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td>td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td><td>Prueba 1</td></tr><tr><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td><td>Prueba 2</td></tr>";
var trOcurrencies= str.match(/<tr>/g).length;
console.log(trOcurrencies);
```